# Find value in table then copy values in different columns to a different table

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table in Sheet1 of a workbook and several rows of the table will have #N/A as their value of column N. I would like to find a way to have a vba macro find all rows that have #N/A in column N then copy the values from column M and L of those rows to the bottom of another table on Sheet2 of the same workbook.

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("SEC_Data").Range.AutoFilter Field:=14, Criteria1:= _
    "#N/A"
Range("M88343:M88351").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("LKUP_Client Name").Select
Range("B2").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row + 1).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Sheets("company_2018 thru2019_gim").Select
Range("L88343:L88351").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("LKUP_Client Name").Select
Range("C").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Range("C" & ActiveCell.Row + 1).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: Filter the data on #N/A and you can copy-paste from M-L.  If you record a macro while doing that it will give you a starting point to work from.

Comment: @Tim Williams I had tried that but I have having trouble getting it to work consistently when the data in the initial table changes

Comment: It's always a good idea to post your current code, even if it's not working (and describe exactly *how* it's not working)  Questions with no code tend to get closed quickly here...

Comment: Yes, get some code, first. In the meantime, you can read about [WorksheetFunction.IsNA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.isna?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm137075)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue) to find #N/A cells...

Comment: @TimWilliams @J VBA I have added code and will read up on the link you sent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I would approach this is to first iterate through column N on sheet 1, when #N/A found then copy the cells and paste in corresponding location on sheet 2. Something like the below:

```
Sub CopyProcedure()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim lRow1 As Long, lRow2 As Long
    Dim wsSheet1 As Worksheet, wsSheet2 As Worksheet

    Set wsSheet1 = Sheets("Sheet 1")
    Set wsSheet2 = Sheets("Sheet 2")

    lRow1 = wsSheet1.Range("N" & wsSheet1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    'assuming your data starts in the first row
    'iterate to the last row of column n
    For i = 1 To lRow1
        'look for the #N/A text
        If wsSheet1.Range("N" & i).Text = "#N/A" Then
            'adjust this to suit which column in sheet 2 you need
            lRow2 = wsSheet2.Range("A" & wsSheet2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            'when text found copy required cells
            wsSheet1.Range("L" & i, "M" & i).Copy
            'paste cell values in required location on sheet 2
            'NOTE THIS WILL PASTE IN THE LAST ROW SPECIFIED ON SHEET 2 AND IN COLUMN A
            'adjust as you see fit
            wsSheet2.Range("A" & lRow2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            'empty clipboard
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End If
    Next i

    Set wsSheet1 = Nothing
    Set wsSheet2 = Nothing

End Sub
```

This is by no means the most efficient way to do it, but I am sure it will get the job done if I understand your problem correctly.

Also, caveat, I haven't tested or debugged this. :)

Comment: Thanks Dean. I will try this and get back to you!

Comment: Hello Dean,
Your solution worked perfectly. I had to edit it slightly to get the information to past correctly but it did exactly what I needed!